# Django and requirements

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Im a bit stuck.  I can't get this configuration to work and I don't know why.  The code I site below is from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04.  The reason I get stuck on it is because he named his project directory and his project the same thing.  If I am right, then where he is locating files like the settings.py and wsgi.py should be /home/user/myproject/myproject/myproject but I'm not sure anymore because I can't even get it right myself.  Earlier in the document he cd's into the directory he created, which would put him in /home/user/myproject.  He then proceeds to create a virtual environment, enter it, and run `django-admin startproject myproject`.  So, if all this holds true, at least what I see on my own server tells me that when you start a django project it actually creates two folders with the same name, nested.  Am I wrong?  Can someone help me straighten the below code out to make more sense?

. . .

```
    Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject:/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

This is what I consistently see in my apache log:

```
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:15.875313 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 47964] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:15.875353 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 47964] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:15.877537 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 47964] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:15.877568 2016] [core:notice] [pid 47964] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.767800 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662] mod_wsgi (pid=47967): Target WSGI script '/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.767851 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662] mod_wsgi (pid=47967): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768339 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768385 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768389 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768395 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768398 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]     django.setup()
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768405 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768408 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768413 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768423 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]     self._setup(name)
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768430 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768433 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768438 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768441 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768446 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768449 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768454 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768460 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768466 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768471 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768477 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768483 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768488 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sun Oct 09 11:48:18.768505 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47967] [remote 192.168.2.249:22662] ImportError: No module named 'servicesite'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You just need to make the directories in the Apache configuration match your directory layout, whatever it is.

Comment: Have you read the official Django documentation on how to set up mod_wsgi? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: @Graham It's the same struggle.  Let's assume I am in `~/projects/projectfolder`.  I then `run django-admin startproject mysite`.  The _django generated_ folder becomes `~/projects/projectfolder/mysite` and the location of settings.py and wsgi.py becomes `~/projects/projectfolder/mysite/mysite`  So when looking at the site documentation, I have to assume mysite.com is just the project folder they created, entered that directory, then created the mysite project.

Comment: @Graham-Dumpleton Adopting the above (keeping in mind I'm using ~ to keep the paths short in this post... Right off the bat `WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py` becomes wrong.  Using my example, `~/projects/projectfolder/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py` would be the correct path to the file, not `~/projects/projectfolder/mysite/wsgi.py`.  Let's assume `mysite.com` was the django-admin project they created, then why is the second level folder `mysite` and not `mysite.com`?  When I create projects, it creates `./projectname/projectname` and `./manage.py` in the project folder.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton and funnily enough, `mysite.com` is not a valid project name, which only proves my point further.

Comment: It isn't great that the Django documentation uses the sample path they do, nor explain it well, but if you work backwards from ``wsgi.py`` and match the two parent directories to what you have and replace them in example, plus the leading path to that point, you should be good. If you find the Django documentation confusing, you have a great opportunity to provide feedback to the Django developers via their issue tracker and suggest/provide improvements to the documentation. Here on SO is not the place to do that as they will not read it here.

Comment: As to general problems with what you are doing, putting stuff under ``/home/user`` is not a good idea as the user that Apache runs as generally can't read anything under your home directory due to restrictive permissions on the home directory. So quite often it will all fail because of that. Since you didn't get to a point of saying that anything specific failed in this question, impossible to guide you if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file add

```
<Directory /home/dimitris/mysite>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

your site.conf file  in the example i load mysite with virtualenv

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myp user=dimitris group=dimitris threads=5  python-path=/home/dimitris/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName mysite
    #ServerAlias mysite
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    WSGIProcessGroup myp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dimitris/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    Alias /favicon.ico /home/dimitris/mysite/favicon.ico
    Alias /media/ /home/dimitris/mysite/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/dimitris/mysite/project-static/
    DocumentRoot /home/dimitris/mysite
    <Directory /home/dimitris/mysite/>
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/mysite-error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/mysite-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

in django wsgi.py file add

```
import os
DJANGO_PATH =  os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..')
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PATH)
```

in the above code replace dimitris with your username

Answer (score 0):

Either you create your project at /home/user or change the apache conf file by appending an extra /myproject wherever you are specifying the path as below:

```
Alias /static /home/user/myproject/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject/myproject:/home/user/myproject/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

It was confusing because you created your project inside a myproject folder(same as your project name), rather than creating it somewhere else.